# Why cant Eloquent in my App Engine app connect to my Google SQL instance?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, eloquent, slim, google-cloud-sql

Oddly enough, I can connect to my Google SQL instance from PHPStorm's database tool, just can't seem to connect locally when deployed.

And when I develop locally - my app connects to my local stack instance (docker) fine using the environment variables below.

Here's my `app.yaml`

```
runtime: php72
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: public/index.php

env_variables:
  MYSQL_DSN: "mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/project:location:sql-instance;dbname=databaseName"
  MYSQL_USER: "username"
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"

runtime_config:
  enable_stackdriver_integration: true
```

And here's how I'm initializing this in Eloquent / Illuminate.

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;

    $db = [];
    if(getenv("MYSQL_DSN")){
        $db = [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'dsn' => getenv("MYSQL_DSN"),
            'username' => getenv("MYSQL_USER"),
            'password' => getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD"),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ];
    } else if(getenv("MYSQL_HOST")){
        $db = [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => getenv("MYSQL_HOST"),
            'database' => getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE"),
            'username' => getenv("MYSQL_USER"),
            'password' => getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD"),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ];
    }

    $settings = [
            // Slim Settings
            'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => false,
            'displayErrorDetails' => true,
            'db' => $db
        ];

    $container = $this->getContainer();
    $capsule = new Manager;
    $capsule->addConnection($settings['db']);

    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    $capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your Cloud SQL instance allow connections from where you're testing? Check the authorized networks under the authorization tab on your [SQL instance page in the GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances/).

If unsure, you can try adding `0.0.0.0/0` to test allowing all IPv4 connections. Turn back off later to prevent unauthorized direct DB connections.

Comment: Thanks for the input! It wasn't that - it turned out it was the DSN I was using. When I specifically set the unix_port and database instead, it worked.